# Regex to exclude parameters in a URL

Tags: regex, parameters, pcre

I need to exclude parameters in the following link:

**https://www.testonetwothree.com/alpha/q.html?&page=1&pp=10&pp_old=20&psize=s&sort=pop&l[]=0&l[1]=three**

This is the regex I have so far, although it is matching it is not being excluded:

```
(\?*[?&]l\[\])|(\?*[?&]l\[[0-9]\]=)
(\?*[?&]sort=)
(\?*[?&]psize=)
(\?*[?&]pp_old=)
```

The l[1] is being restricted successfully, however the rest are not.

Comment: Do you need to exclude the entire query string or just certain parameters?

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: Which language are you using? Also, you never mention what you want done with `page=1`?

Comment: You're missing `|` between your regex subpatterns. Also, you may not have activated the `x` (ignore whitespace) flag. You may want to use something like [`(?<=[?&])(?:sort|psize|pp_old|l\[\d*\])=`](https://regex101.com/r/L5QsDP/1) instead. It's simpler and improves performance rather than making the engine backtrack for each option. Your existing regex would take 1206 steps against your example (given the changes I specify) whereas mine would only take 230.

Comment: The language I am using is PCRE. page=1? needs to be kept, so I do not want to exclude it. I want to exclude any request/URL containing either one of those parameters that I listed

Answer (score 0):

This revised example will capture the url including the ? in one group, and then pass the page parameter into a second group.

```
^([^?]+\?).*(page=\d+)
```

[Regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/opBcTO/1/)

Comment: You shouldn't answer when you're missing information. For example, which language is the OP using? This may be even simpler if a method already exists, i.e. PHP has the method [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). Also, this will get rid of `page=1` which is not explicitly mentioned by the OP as a parameter that they want to drop. Also, you don't need to escape `?` inside a character class.

Comment: I think this is too greedy for this case. I want to exclude these specific parameters